# Combining Convergence in Distribution and Almost Surely

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems, almost-everywhere

Suppose I know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}X(mt)\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{d} B(t)$ where $B$ is Brownian motion, and that $\alpha(mt)/m \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$. Then I am trying to prove the following convergence:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}X(mt+\alpha(mt))\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{d} B(t)
$$
My approach is to try and prove as follows. Fix $t,x,\epsilon$. So by the continuity of the density of $B(t)$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|s-t|<\delta \implies |\mathbb{P}(B(s)\leq x)-\mathbb{P}(B(t)\leq x)|<\epsilon$. Then since $\alpha(mt)/m \to 0$ almost surely, therefore:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}X\left(m(t+\alpha(mt)/m)\right)\leq x\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}X\left(m(t+\alpha(mt)/m)\right)\leq x, \quad \exists M\; s.t.\; m>M\implies |\alpha(mt)/m|<\delta\right)
$$
And I want at this point to say that this converges to $B(s)$ in distribution for some $s$ such that $|s-t|<\delta$, so then since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this converges in distribution to $B(t)$. This seems intuitive enough, however it is this step when I somehow want to use the almost sure convergence within the $\mathbb{P}(.)$ which is the step I am unsure on. Do I need more justification than this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the convergence of distributions (and a.s.) here in the premise? e.g. local uniform topology, Skorokhod topology?

Comment: Skorokhod topology

Comment: Should it make a difference @Snoop

Comment: The question seemed to imply convergence at fixed $t$, while instead you need functional convergence. An entirely different beast if you ask me!

Comment: Ah yes I see... I should've said that it the question!

Comment: Also pposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457242/functional-clt-with-an-asymptotically-small-time-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this answer at MathSE also.

Here, use your symbols, a proof will be given under following condition (1):
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{m\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\Big(\sup_{0\le t\le 1}\Big| \frac{\alpha(mt)}{m} \Big| \ge\delta \Big)=0,\qquad \forall \delta>0. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{align*}
 Y_m(t) &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}X(mt), \tag{2} \\
 Z_m(t) &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}X\big(m(t+\tfrac{\alpha(mt)}{m})\big)
    =Y_m\big(t+\tfrac{\alpha(mt)}{m}\big),  \tag{3}\\
 U_m(t) &=Z_m(t)-Y_m(t)=Y_m\big(t+\tfrac{\alpha(mt)}{m}\big) - Y_m(t).   \tag{4}
\end{align*}

In the following, the concept of modulus of continuity of an arbitrary function $x(.)$ on $[0,1]$ also be used(cf. P. Billingsley, *Convergence of Probability Measures*, 2ed. $\S$7, pp 80-81). Let
\begin{equation*}
 w(x,\delta)=\sup_{|s-t|\le \delta}|x(s)-x(t)|, \qquad 0<\delta \le 1.
\end{equation*}
For fixed $\delta>0$, since
\begin{equation*}
  |w(x,\delta)-w(y,\delta)|\le 2\sup\limits_{0\le t\le 1}|x(t)-y(t)|,
\end{equation*}
$w(x,\delta)$ is continuous in $x$,
using this and $Y_m\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}B$(i.e., the distributions of $Y_m$ converge to to the distribution of BM $B$ weakly on $C[0,1]$), get
\begin{gather*}
\lim_{m\to\infty}w(Y_m,\delta)\stackrel{d}{=} w(B,\delta), \qquad \forall \delta>0,\\
 \varlimsup_{m\to\infty} \mathsf{P}(w(Y_m,\delta)\ge \epsilon)\le \mathsf{P}(w(B,\delta) \ge \epsilon)\quad \forall \epsilon,\delta>0, \\
 \lim_{\delta\to0}\varlimsup_{m\to\infty} \mathsf{P}(w(Y_m,\delta) \ge \epsilon)=0, \quad  \forall \epsilon>0.\tag{5}
\end{gather*}
Next, the following fact will be proved,
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{m\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|U_m(t)|>\epsilon)=0, \quad
 \forall \epsilon>0. \tag{6}
\end{equation*}
Denote
\begin{equation*}
 A_m(\delta)=\Big\{\omega: \sup_{0\le t\le 1}\Big| \frac{\alpha(mt)}{m} \Big| \ge \delta \Big\},
\end{equation*}
then from (1)
\begin{gather*}
 \lim_{m\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(A_m(\delta))=0,  \qquad \forall \delta>0,\\
 \lim_{m\to\infty}\mathsf{P}([\sup_t|U_m(t)|]I_{A_m(\delta)}>\epsilon)=0, \qquad \forall \delta, \epsilon>0.  \tag{7}
\end{gather*}
On the other hand,
\begin{gather*}
 |U_m(t)| I_{A_m^c(\delta)}\le w(Y_m,\delta), \qquad \forall t\in[0,1],\\
 [\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|U_m(t)|]I_{A_m^c(\delta)}\le w(Y_m,\delta). \tag{8}
\end{gather*}
From (8),(5), get
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{\delta\to0}\varlimsup_{m\to\infty} \mathsf{P}([\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|U_m(t)|]I_{A_m^c(\delta)}>\epsilon)=0, \quad  \forall \epsilon>0.\tag{9}
\end{equation*}
Hence, from (7)and (9),  (6) is true. Furthermore, $Z_m\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}B$ comes from $Y_m\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}B$ and (4),(6).